# PHP PDO update query HTML characters from class

Tags: php, html, class, pdo, character

I'm using a simple update query like:

> $db->query("UPDATE " . TBL_NAME . " SET title = :title, content =
>   :content WHERE id =
>   :id",array("title"=>$title,"content"=>$content,"id"=>$id));

Only my 'content' field/textarea is an WYSIWYG Editor, so it put HTML chars in the post, but the query does the update without the HTML tags (strong,p,li,etc.)

I saw on a forum that I probably need the following line:
$db->bindValue(':$content', $content, PDO::PARAM_STR);
instead of:
$db->bindValue(':$content', $content);

How do I get the 'PDO::PARAM_STR' connected to the 'content' field with this class? Or is there another way to do this

Can somebody please help me out?

*ps: I use this class:
https://github.com/indieteq/PHP-MySQL-PDO-Database-Class*

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `:` characters in your parameter names:

```
array("title"=>$title,"content"=>$content,"id"=>$id)
```

...should be:

```
array(":title"=>$title,":content"=>$content,":id"=>$id)
```

Comment: Normally yes, but i'm using the CLASS from github (see url above) - it works though, the only thing that doesn't work is saving the HTML characters into the CONTENT field (btw.thanks for the reply)